# How do I disable this new feature that shows the start of the function in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Earlier, when I used to navigate through a file in vscode, it never used to show the first few lines of the function I'm in, but now it does.

Please tell me how do I disable this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8P07.png)

I have tried going through the settings, but couldn't find anything, as I do not know what this feature is called.

Comment: can we show an answer to this `sticky scroll` problem when people ask a question with the `visual-studio-code` tag

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for

```
Editor › Sticky Scroll: Enabled
```

You can look for this settings inside vscode and disable it

Comment: please check for a duplicate target before answering.